# Handling requests and responses in protocols over TCP

Tags: iphone, tcp

I am actually not sure how to find the best title for my question but please let me explain ...

In my app I have to implement a question/answer type of protocol over TCP where the client sends a question, waits for one or more answers to only then send the subsequent question.

The questions are just send normally, while the received answers trigger the callback `-(void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag`

Here the main loop:

```
- (void) doQandA {
    BOOL ok;
    int runMessages[7] = {0,1,2,3,2,0,3};
    int msgIndex = 0;
    int msgNumber = runMessages[msgIndex];

    waitingForResponse = FALSE;
    while (msgIndex < 6) {
        if (!waitingForResponse) {
          ok = [self sendQuestionMsg: msgNumber];
          msgIndex++;
          msgNumber = runMessages[msgIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

where sending is actually...

```
- (void) sendQuestionMsg: (int) msgNo {

    //sendMsg over TCP
    [self sendQuestionNo: msgNo];
    waitingForResponse = TRUE;
}
```

And receiving the answer...

```
-(void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
    [self handleAnswer: data];
}

-(void) handleAnswer: (NSData*) data {
  //do stuff
   waitingForResponse = FALSE;
}
```

Is this actually the right way of doing this? I am afraid that my main doQandA loop is just too CPU intensive. Isn't there a better way waiting for the answers ?

I hope I could clarify my question...
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, this isn't the right approach.

What you've implemented is called a *busy-wait* loop.  The loop in `doQandA()` spins, constantly executing, all the time - you're definitely right to worry about that.

The right thing to do is to have a blocking call within that loop - a call that suspends your process until an event occurs.  In this case, the event that you're waiting for is a network packet to arrive.

The usual way to do this is to block on a syscall like `read()`, `recv()`, `poll()` or `select()`, which will return when a network packet arrives.  You would then dispatch the `didReadData()` function directly from the main loop.